# Multiple sequential Observables depend on a single Observable

Tags: rxjs, observable

I am curious about a better way to write the following scenario.

Assume I have a `userObservable` fetches user data (user) from db then I'd like to

- Validate some input with `user`, `validateObservable`
- After get some external data with `user`, `getExternalObservable`
- After combine externalData with `user` and update db again, `updateDbObservable`
- In the end I'd like to get this updated user data.

Normally I can do this as below, but this code looks repetitive and produces a little bit ugly map -> forkJoin -> mergeAll boilerplate.

```js
userObservable.pipe(
  map((user) => {
    return forkJoin({
      user: of(user),
      verifyResult: verifyObservable(user)
    });
  },

  mergeAll(),

  map(({ user }) => {
    return forkJoin({
      user: of(user),
      externalData : getExternalObservable(user)
    });
  }),
  
  mergeAll(),

  map(({user, externalData}) => {
    return updateDbObservable(user, externalData);
  }),

  mergeAll(),
);
```

Thank you !

Comment: As a sidenote, a `map` followed by a `mergeAll` is really just a `mergeMap`

Answer (score 1):

You can greatly simplify your code by doing the following:

- define a `verifiedUser` observable that only emits when verification passes
- use nested pipes so the most inner call has access to emissions from other observables

```js
const verifiedUser = userObservable.pipe(
  switchMap(user => verifyObservable(user).pipe(
    catchError(() => EMPTY),
    map(() => user)
  ))
);
```

Here we declare an observable that will emit the user only when verification passes.

```js
const updateDbResult = verifiedUser.pipe(
  switchMap(user => getExternalObservable(user).pipe(
    switchMap(externalData => updateDbObservable(user, externalData))
  ))
);
```

Here we add a `.pipe()` to each observable inside the `switchMap`:

When `verifiedUser` emits, the results flow to `getExternalObservable()`, then finally the `updateDbObservable()`.

Notice that the most inner call has access to all prior emitted values so there's no need to fabricate an object using `forkJoin` / `of`.

---

##### Separate Observables

In the above code we've defined separate smaller observables that can make it easier to follow the logic. If we need to alter what it means to be a "verified user", we don't need to change our `updateDbResult` observable at all!

Comment: Very informative! Mostly I'd like to avoid nesting, it's sometimes bad for eye health :) Using separate observables is really making the code cleaner, especially when it comes to understanding the business logic.
Only a small thing, `updateDbObservable` also depends on `user` object. So is there a way to add that into combineLatest ?

Comment: Oops, I misread your original code.  I've updated my answer to reflect that `updateDbObservable` accepts "user" and "externalDate" (*instead of verifyResult*).

Answer (score 1):

```
userObservable.pipe(
  switchMap(user =>
    of(user).pipe(
      tap(verifyObservable),
      catchError(() => EMPTY), // means "skip if an error occurs"
      // In our case, that means if it wasn't verified/validated
    )
  )
  switchMap(user => 
    getExternalObservable(user).pipe(
      map(externalData => ({ user, externalData })),
    )
  ),
  switchMap(({ user, externalData }) => {
    // I'll assume `updateDbObservable` emits the updated user value as well
    // otherwise, simply pipe a `map(() => user)` to the result of `updateDbObservable`
    return updateDbObservable(user, externalData);
  }),
  share(), // Avoids duplicating DB queries if you have multiple subscriptions to this observable
);
```

Unlike `Promise`s, we don't have a nice alternative syntax like `async`/`await`. So we're forced to use the "continuation tricks" we did with promises to drag the previous result along. In the case of `Promise`s, `.then` is both `map` and `flatMap`. Here, [`map`](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/map) is `map` and [`switchMap`](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/switchMap) (or [`mergeMap`](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/mergeMap) if you don't want the switching optimization) is `flatMap`.

Comment: `verifyObservable` is intended to check input with `user` if it fails throws error. I didn't include to keep the main logic simple. For beginners seeing `!!x` somewhat a bit scary, so I'd like to avoid that if possible. `filter(verifyObservable)` is on to the point, I'd like to filter out inputs which is not verified.

However again we're including `user` to each operations return objects. 
Is there a way to combine main observable `userObservable` and it's dependent `verifyObservable ` and `getExternalObservable` then send them to the last `updateDbObservable` ?

Comment: I see, given the function naming I assumed it returned an observable. `filter(verifyObservable)` was what I had originally. It still works if your verification function returns a boolean instead of throwing. I'll edit to take into account the fact that it throws

Comment: As for the combining, my answer is the "linear" version that respects the sequential nature of your workflow. This is the same dilemma we had with `Promise`s or the nested callback hell, and it was solved by introducing `async`/`await` which is just syntactic sugar for what we used to write.